# How to give custom color to tree map in anychart.js

Tags: javascript, treemap, anychart

I am creating this tree map and I have different values What I want is different shades of colors(green for postive and red for negative)  on different ranges of points. The issue is in my callback function I am accessing the value parameter but points is not available.
Also the second issue is I want the font size according to the size of the box. As there are some boxes which are very big but the font size looks very small. I think If i get that color  part fix I can set the fontsize on my own

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https:/cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-treemap.min.js"></script>
    <title>My First JavaScript Treemap Chart</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <style>
        span {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
            var chart = anychart.treeMap(getData(), "as-tree");

            chart.maxDepth(2);

            chart.hintDepth(1);

            chart.hintOpacity(0.7);

            chart.labels().useHtml(true);
            chart.labels().format(
                "<span style='font-weight:bold; color: #fff;'>{%name}</span><br>{%points}"
            );

            chart.tooltip().useHtml(true);
            chart.tooltip().format(
                "COMPANY : {%name}%<br>PERCENTAGE CHANGE: {%points}%<br>MARKET CAP: {%points}<br>VOLUME: {%points}<br>"
            );

            chart.container("container");

            chart.draw();

            var customColorScale = anychart.scales.linearColor();
            customColorScale.colors(["green", "red",]);
            console.log(chart)

            chart.colorScale(customColorScale);

            // chart.colorRange().enabled(true);
            chart.colorRange().length("100%");
            chart.fontColor = 'white'

            chart.fill(coloringFunction);



            function coloringFunction(value, points, name) {

                console.log(value)
                if (this.value < 0) {
                    return 'red'

                }
                else if (this.value > 0) {
                    return 'red'
                }

            }

            /*chart.title().useHtml(true);
            chart.title(
                "<span style='font-size:18; font-style:bold'>PSX TREE MAP </span><br><i><span style='font-size:14; font-style:italic'>UPDATED(7:11 PM)</i>"
            );*/

        });

        // get data
        function getData() {
            // create data
            var data = [
                {
                    name: "PAKISTAN STOCK EXCHANGE",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "TECH ",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "HUMNL",
                                    value: 24,
                                    points: 0.26

                                },
                                {
                                    name: "TRG",
                                    value: 6,
                                    points: 2.3
                                    ,
                                    points: 0.26

                                },
                                {
                                    name: "SYS",
                                    value: 55,
                                    points: 4.26


                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "SUGAR & ALLIED INDUSTRIES ",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "AGSML",
                                    value: 12,
                                    points: 2.26



                                },
                                {
                                    name: "MIRKS",
                                    value: 14,
                                    points: 3.26
                                    ,

                                },
                                {
                                    name: "ALNRS",
                                    value: 15,
                                    points: 0.26

                                }
                            ]
                        },
                      



                    ]
                }
            ];

            return data;
        }


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the coloring you should provide ABS value for the "size" field in the data. But the "value" field may reflect positive/negative values.
Like this:

```
{name: "Point 1",        value: -11443830, size: 11443830}
```

Exactly the "value" field is used for linear and ordinal coloring. The treemap supports both, you can learn more about it in [the documentation article](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Treemap_Chart#color_scale).
In your case, you can create and adjust linear scale like this:

```
  // create and configure a color scale.
  var customColorScale = anychart.scales.linearColor();
  customColorScale.minimum(-100000000).maximum(100000000);
  customColorScale.colors(["red", "green"]);

  // set the color scale as the color scale of the chart
  chart.colorScale(customColorScale);
```

Min/max apply as you need or do not apply it to calculate them automatically.

To adjust label fontsize for every item simply enable adjustFontSize() setting:

```
  chart.labels().adjustFontSize(true);
```

For details, check the sample we prepared.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

  // create data
  var data = [
    {name:   "European Union", children: [
      {name: "Belgium",        value: -11443830, size: 11443830},
      {name: "France",         value: 64938716, size: 64938716},
      {name: "Germany",        value: 80636124, size: 80636124},
      {name: "Greece",         value: -10892931, size: 10892931},
      {name: "Italy",          value: 59797978, size: 59797978},
      {name: "Netherlands",    value: -17032845, size: 17032845},
      {name: "Poland",         value: 38563573, size: 38563573},
      {name: "Romania",        value: -19237513, size: 19237513}, 
      {name: "Spain",          value: 46070146, size: 46070146},
      {name: "United Kingdom", value: 65511098, size: 65511098}  
    ]} 
  ];

  // create a chart and set the data
  var chart = anychart.treeMap(data, "as-tree");

  // create and configure a color scale.
  var customColorScale = anychart.scales.linearColor();
  customColorScale.minimum(-100000000).maximum(100000000);
  customColorScale.colors(["red", "green"]);

  // set the color scale as the color scale of the chart
  chart.colorScale(customColorScale);

  // add a color range
  chart.colorRange().enabled(true);
  chart.colorRange().length("80%");
  
  chart.labels().adjustFontSize(true);

  // set the container id
  chart.container("container");

  // initiate drawing the chart
  chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.10.0/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```